# Como ir cambiando los valores de 3 combos select anidados de acuerdo al valor de los anteriores con javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Como explique, tengo 3 combos en html, necesito ir actualizando los posibles valores del 2do combo de acuerdo al valor seleccionado en el primer combo, y luego a su vez el 3er combo irlo cambiando de valor de acuerdo al valor del 2do combo, es el clasico problema de pais provincia ciudad... pero hay un problema, estos valores de los combos no estan relacionados con una FK, yo he resuelto este problema para tablas padres e hijos con javascript, con

```js
        <script>

            $(document).ready(function () {

                $.get("GetCiudadPorId", { ID: $("#ProvinciaIdFk").val() }, function (data) {
                    $("#LocalidadIdFk").prop('disabled', false);
                    if (data && data == "") {
                        $("#LocalidadIdFk").append("<option value='ignore'>Sin informacion</option>")
                        $("#LocalidadIdFk").prop('disabled', true);
                    }
                    $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                        $("#LocalidadIdFk").append("<option value='" + row.ciudadId + "'>" + row.nombre + "</option>")
                    });
                })

            });

            $(function () {
                $("#ProvinciaIdFk").change(function () {
                    $.get("GetCiudadPorId", { ID: $("#ProvinciaIdFk").val() }, function (data) {
                        $("#LocalidadIdFk").empty();
                        $("#LocalidadIdFk").prop('disabled', false);
                        console.log(data);
                        if (data && data == "") {
                            $("#LocalidadIdFk").append("<option value='ignore'>Sin informacion</option>")
                            $("#LocalidadIdFk").prop('disabled', true);
                        }
                        $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                            $("#LocalidadIdFk").append("<option value='" + row.ciudadId + "'>" + row.nombre + "</option>")
                        });
                    })
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Pero ahora necesito filtrar los combos de acuerdo a comparaciones en la base de datos: mis combos son :

Tipo de ingreso ( posibles datos: 1 y 2 )
Categorias ( para la fuente 1 ( a,b,c,d,e,f ) para la fuente 2: ( g,h,i,j )
y Fuente ( cada categoria puede ser fuente 1 o 2 o ambas )

Aca el codigo HTML de mis combos: ( lo que necesito es adaptar mi codigo de pais - provincia - ciudad a estos combos para filtrar en vivo... pero no se como resolver el back end...

```html
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Input_us_type_id" class="control-label col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"></label>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <select asp-for="Input_us_type_id" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Input_us_type_id"></select>
                                <span asp-validation-for="Input_us_type_id" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="BusinessRule.Source_id_fk" class="control-label col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"></label>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <select asp-for="BusinessRule.Source_id_fk" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Source_id_fk"></select>
                                <span asp-validation-for="BusinessRule.Source_id_fk" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="BusinessRule.Category_id_fk" class="control-label col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"></label>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <select asp-for="BusinessRule.Category_id_fk" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Category_id_fk"></select>
                                <span asp-validation-for="BusinessRule.Category_id_fk" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Dependiendo del país estos códigos generalmente los puedes encontrar ya hechos. O si quieres crearlos a tu estilo puedes usar DB, arreglos.. como en este ejemplo -> [link](https://codepen.io/amigaviole/pen/NQOpKM?editors=1010)

Comment: Gracias! puedo generar los campos que yo quiero filtrar desde esos textos para usar con javascript ? total el id y el post en el modelo no cambian, cierto ?

Comment: Puedes utilizar los campos que tu consideres necesarios en tu pais->region->provincia->ciudad->villa.... lo que sea jajaja Empieza probando pequeño, no te vayas a perder

Comment: gracias! lo voy a probar!